# Angular 2+ Prevent user to navigate back to Auth0 callback

Tags: angular, auth0

My Angular app uses `auth0`, and after the login is successful, auth0 will redirect the user to my website's `/callback`.

It's working completely fine, but I want to prevent the user to reach this `/callback` state by hitting the "previous page" button for example.

Because navigating to `/callback` after being succesfully authenticated will display an error.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: why not check if the user is authenticated in the /callback ? and if so redirect

Comment: Yes of course, but I would like to make /callback unreachable, like it does not exist.

Comment: maybe history.replaceState will help
if you call that beore redirecting out of the callback the history entry wont exist

https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/History/replaceState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_router.navigate([your, redirect, route], { replaceUrl: true });` to replace current state.
https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#replaceUrl